# Route redirecting issue with devise and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a `has_one` association in my model with my user. What I'm trying to do here is simple but I'm having a hard time understanding whats wrong here. So since I have a has_one association with my model, in my mind I was simply thinking that if the user has already created the model associated with the `has_one` association if he tries accessing `"localhost3000/model/new"` I would redirect him to the edit page of this particular model. Here is what I have but its telling me its not working as intended. It's as if my if statement is not catching anything

```
class BusinessesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_business, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @businesses = Business.all
    @buzzs = Buzz.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    if current_user.business.nil?
      @business = current_user.build_business
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @business = current_user.build_business(business_params)

    if @business.save
      redirect_to @business, notice: 'Business was successfully created.' 
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

This error does not make a lot of sense to me because it says its an error in the "new" controller which would have rendered it to the edit path thus not being nil

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you're not setting `@business` when redirecting to 'edit'. Try this:

```
def new 
 if current_user.business.nil? 
    @business = current_user.build_business 
 else 
    @business = current_user.business 
    render 'edit' 
 end 
end
```